# MatLab: Large time inputting matix elements? Vectorization the solution?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have some MatLab function which calculates a Wavelet Bispectrum. In this a matrix is initialised and values (complex) are put in it after they are calculated in nested for loops. However when I time the the entire function I see a third of the time (~1000s) is spent adding these values to the matrix.

The Matrix size is (1025 x 1025) and so about 1million values are input. If I generate random numbers and put them in a matrix in a similar way it takes less than I second. So why is it taking up so much time in my code?

Anyone able to help me out?

I've included a sample of the code. It is putting the million or so values into the Bisp Matrix that takes over 1000s. WT is a matrix containing complex values and freq is a vector containing all the values that match the 1st dimension of the WT matrix.

`

```
nfreq = 1025;
Bisp = nan(nfreq, nfreq);
Norm = nan(nfreq, nfreq);

for j = 1 : nfreq
    for k = 1 : nfreq 
        f3 = freq(j) + freq(k);
        if f3 <= freq(end)
            idx3 = find(freq <= f3);
            idx3 = idx3(end);
            x = (WT(j, :) .* WT(k, :)) .* conj(WT(indx3, :));
            bb = nansum(x);           
            norm1 = nansum(abs(WT(j, :) .* WT(k, :)).^2);
            norm2 = nansum(abs(WT(idx3, :).^2));
            a = sqrt(norm1 * norm2);
            Norm(j, k) = a;
            Bisp(j, k) = bb;      **This takes about 1000seconds**

       end
    end
end
```

`

Comment: Normally you would speed this up using vectorization, but unless that's the actual calculation you're using to get the matrix elements, we can't really help you do that.

Comment: @beaker That is essentially the code, it does contain an if statement. I shall put the full thing in the original question.